# VSC Setting default compiler to clang++ -std=c++17 or g++ -std=c++17

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

How can I change the default settings when compiling in VSC to clang++ -std=c++17 or g++ -std=c++17.

For now I need to include the arg in the tasks.json

```
"tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "/usr/bin"
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

If it is not written in there VSC Compiles with c++98 and put outs a lot of errors.

Thanks for any help:)

Comment: So using this tasks.json works as intended for you? Then what is your question? There is no default compiler in VSC, use an extension or the tasks like you currently do.

Comment: And is there any extension to set it. I use as extension the C/C++ of Microsoft and then I have the option to Build and Debug Active file. Then I can choose if using clang++ or g++.

Comment: @super but there I can choose the argument -std=c++17

Comment: It is still very unclear to me what your question is. What exactly is not working? Are you looking for help to edit your `tasks.json`? Just pointing it to clang instead of g++ could be one way to do this. You need to edit your question so it's clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: @super my question is if there is an option to change the c_cpp_properties.json so that it compiles using g++ -std=c++17

Comment: I also recommend trying to be more specific with your question. The `c_cpp_properties.json` file is used for intellisense not building. To compile in VSC you create a build task and as you have posted you can change `command` to point to either gcc or clang and you can edit `args` to use c++17 or another standard. AFAIK there is not yet a global way to set the compiler for intellisense other than changing your systems default compiler. There is an open issue to enable global tasks:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1435